# Discrete Mathematics books for Computer Science Self-study

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, discrete-mathematics

I am an experienced software developer, want to refresh discrete math back in uni.

I am looking for a book that is easy to read, contains more examples, and exercises and solutions for self study beginner.

There are two books below that are recommended by others. Which one should I pick:

- [Susanna S. Epp's Discrete Mathematics with Applications 4th 2010](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0495391328)
- [Kenneth Rosen's Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications 7th 2011](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0073383090)

Below are their books in uk, one of which I will buy based on the US edition.

- [Susanna S. Epp's Discrete Mathematics with Applications 4th 2011](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Discrete-Mathematics-Applications-Susanna-Epp/dp/0495826162/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1400191447&sr=8-1&keywords=Discrete%20Mathematics%20with%20Applications)
- [Kenneth Rosen's Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications Global Edition](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Discrete-Mathematics-Applications-Global-Edition/dp/0071315012/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1400191606&sr=8-1&keywords=Kenneth%20Rosen%27s%20Discrete%20Mathematics%20and%20Its%20Applications)

Comment: The answer is likely to be subjective. It appears that both are pretty standard books, so there isn't a "better" one among them. They are just two different choices. Perhaps Amazon has a few reviews which compare the two books.

Comment: Either one. Or both, if you can afford them... why not? You can always sell/donate one if you don't find it useful.

Comment: That will work. But it takes more time to learn one thing.

Comment: I used the Epp book in school and thought it was well written. The reviews on your links seem be a pretty clear indicator of which the public prefers.